# Unable to view the images in kaggle's imported dataset, terminal message "Failed to fetch JPEG asset"

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing, classification, kaggle

```
import os
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random as rd
import gc
train_dir = '../input/classification/train'
test_dir = '../input/classification/test'
alai_minar = ['../input/classification/train/{}'.format(i) for i in os.listdir(train_dir) if 
'alai_minar' in i]
iron_pillar = ['../input/classification/train/{}'.format(i) for i in os.listdir(train_dir) if 
'iron_pillar' in i]
alai_darwaza = ['../input/classification/train/{}'.format(i) for i in os.listdir(train_dir) if 
'alai_darwaza' in i]
#jamli_kamali_tomb =  ['../input/classification/train/{}'.format(i) for i in os.listdir(train_dir) if 
'jamli_kamali_tomb' in i]
 qutub_minar =  ['../input/classification/train/{}'.format(i) for i in os.listdir(train_dir) if 
 'qutub_minar' in i]

train_img = [alai_minar,iron_pillar,alai_darwaza,qutub_minar]
test_img = ['../input/test/{}'.format(i) for i in os.listdir(test_dir)]

#rd.shuffle(train_img)

#mplt.plot([i for i in range(100)],[i*i for i in range(100)],'r')
#mplt.show()

for i in test_img:
   for j in i:
    #print(j)
    #plt.imshow(j)
    #plt.show()
    #plt.imshow(i.reshape(i.shape[0],i.shape[1]), cmap=plt.cm.Greys)
     #img = mpimg.imread(i)
     #imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
     #plt.show()
     #print(i,' -- ')
     plt.plot(j)
     plt.show()
    #cv2.imshow(i)
```

I'm sorry if the structure of the question is not up to the mark as this is my first question here,
so I'm trying to get these images from kaggle notebook to display but I'm getting blank frames with no image data in them what's wrong here[blank frames of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9ZxW.jpg)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see this example of [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I hope you get the answer you need.

Comment: If your question is about opening an image, please remove all the plotting stuff, all the pandas stuff all the loops and show the simplest code that describes your issue. You will then probably find you don't need us at all and will learn lots. If not, we'll be able to help so much better.